# The variable $_POST is empty in midway of code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a plugin for WordPress with Meta Box metadata saving feature. Here is a portion of code below,

```
update_option("pdev_pre_nonce2", $_POST["pdev-book-details"]);   // $_POST["pdev-book-details"] has a value here received from form submission.
// Check if not Nonce field (CSRF Token) exists or if not verified abort.
if(
    ! isset($_POST["pdev-book-details"]) ||
    ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST["pdev-book-details"], basename(__FILE__))
) {
    update_option("pdev_post_nonce2", $_POST["pdev-book-details"]); // But here $_POST["pdev-book-details"] is null
    return;
}
```

Look at the comments above in the code. How can $_POST["pdev-book-details"] be set at first and in the midway it becomes null.

Comment: Have you verified this by dumping `$_POST`?

Comment: Yes, I did it. update_option is for debugging like dumping

Comment: And this code is called exactly in this order, there isn't anything between the original `update_option` and the `if` condition that you've maybe left out in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying in your condition to execute the midway code only if
`! isset($_POST["pdev-book-details"])`, so that part of code will be executed only if pdev-book-details is not set.

Comment: There is || in the condition and the 2nd condition is true. the line before the return statement is not actually in the code. I added it for debugging.